# Redirection to app from specific site Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, redirect, deep-linking

I need to implement the redirection to my app when user clicks the link that begins with `https://api.iamnearby.net/confirm` So I am following [this](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking?hl=ru) article. But there is no any redirection. Here is my manifest code:
`

```
<application
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
   android:supportsRtl="true"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
   <activity  android:name="url_entry_activity">
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       <data android:scheme="https"
             android:host="api.iamnearby.net"
             android:pathPrefix="/confirm"/>
     </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyDmY-2x_MMhUZet8yenxILDXt********" />
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
 </application>
`
```

What can be wrong here?

Comment: what happens when you try htis `adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://api.iamnearby.net/confirm" com.example.android.YOURAPPHERE`

Comment: @ZUNJAE, it works normally when I use ADB. It started needed activity.

Comment: ok then it's a browser issue. I am suspecting that Chrome blocks redirecting to apps (to fight spam etc.) I had this same issue before but gave up figuring out a solution. I read that you had to use a specific url to open your application

Comment: So it is impossible to figure it out from my app?

Comment: Can you show us how the redirection is done on the web site? (is it hml or js script)

Comment: I dont have this code for now. Let me describe a problem. When the user registers in our app he receives email with a link. I found how to do it working. All I need that is the link that contains url that opens my app. I have already prepared such an url (`<a href="iamnearby://register_activate">Press to confirm the registration</a>`) I have put this link into html file. And this link opened my needed activity from browser. Our backend developer asked me to search if it possible to be redirected to app from email without my specific link only by pressing on `https://api.iamnearby.net/confirm`